# Android onScroll to load more results from MySQL/PHP/JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am looking for a way to impliment an onScroll listener into my listview. I have read a lot about using:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But, I honestly can't figure out how to implement it into my working code.

Currently, I pull a bunch of records into the listview from a MySQL database using PHP (JSON Response). Everything works fine, but I want to limit the number of records returned when the activity is first launched (which I know is done with the SQL statement within the PHP script) and then when the user scrolls to have it load older posts and append them to the current listview. I have looked at NUMEROUS examples, but I can't find any that relate to my current structure.

Here is my current code: (LiveFeed.java)

```
public class LiveFeed extends SherlockListActivity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Used To Put Dark Icons On Light Action Bar
    boolean isLight = ThemeList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock;

    // Build Action Bar
    menu.add("Refresh")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_refresh : R.drawable.ic_refresh_inverse).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("+ Add Post")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}

// Define Menu Item Actions
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String menuItemTitle = item.getTitle().toString();
    if(menuItemTitle.equals("Refresh")){
        // Clear ArrayList
        posts.clear();
        // Re-Run AsyncTask
        new FeedTask().execute();
    }
    if(menuItemTitle.equals("+ Add Post")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPost.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}

private ArrayList<Feed> posts = new ArrayList<Feed>();

// Define JSON Nodes
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_POST = "post";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "post_time";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(ThemeList.THEME);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load All Posts
    new FeedTask().execute();

    // Get ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Selecting Single List Item Starts EditPost Activity
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postid)).getText().toString();
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditPost.class);
            // sending Post Id To EditPost Activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, pid);
            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });
}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // If Result Code 100 (edited/deleted post) - Reload Screen
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

// AsyncTask To Pull In All Posts And Build ListView
private class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LiveFeed.this,"", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/android/login/get_posts.php");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Feed feed = new Feed();
                feed.id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);
                feed.post = json_data.getString(TAG_POST);
                feed.post_time = json_data.getString(TAG_TIME);
                posts.add(feed);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error loading JSON", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        setListAdapter(new FeedListAdaptor(LiveFeed.this, R.layout.feed, posts));
    }
}

private class FeedListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Feed> {
    private ArrayList<Feed> posts;
    public FeedListAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Feed> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.posts = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed, null);
        }
        Feed o = posts.get(position);
        TextView ht = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postid);
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        ht.setText(o.id);
        tt.setText(o.post);
        bt.setText(o.post_time);
        return v;
    }
}

// Define Variables Used To Build Feed
public class Feed {
    String id;
    String post;
    String post_time;
}
```

}

And the PHP script that pulls the results: (get_posts.php)

```
include('config.php');
$q=mysql_query("SELECT f.id, f.post, DATE_FORMAT(f.post_time, '%b %D, %Y %r') AS post_time, f.updated, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM feed f
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=f.user__id WHERE archived='0' ORDER BY f.id DESC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
$output[]=$row;
print json_encode($output);
mysql_close();
```

I am thinking about passing a starting number within the initial post to tell the PHP script how many results to pull back. Then on each time it fetches results during the scroll, return the next number to use as the LIMIT in the next SQL query called from the onScroll(). (Right now I don't have any LIMIT set on my SQL query.)

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: I think it is always good to look for some librarary like [this](http://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on something similar. You can use setOnScrollListener to your ListView and implement it like this:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    boolean isLastItemVisible = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount;

    if (isLastItemVisible) {
        listOverscrolled();
    }

}
```

Than in listOverscrolled method do something like this:

```
    if (!isLoadingData()) {
      setLoadingData(true);
      loadData(); 
}
```

and in loadData method start new AsyncTask that loads data.
What I did was appending the id of last downloaded record to the url query and in SQL query add condition WHERE id > last_id. It is important to return them in the same order every time more records are requested.

so in your case it would be something like this:

```
 lastId = feedListAdapter.get(feedListAdapter.count());
    ... and in AsyncTask ...
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/android/login/get_posts.php?lastid=" + lastId);
```

than in OnPostExecute you can do something like:

```
 setLoading(false);
    feedListAdapter.addAll(feeds);
    feedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Of course your adapter must be created earlier.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help! This definitely is pointing me in the right direction. I am still very new to Java/Android, so I'm still getting quite a few errors when trying to implement this into my current working code. Does the onScroll() go within the onCreate() method? Also, do I need to make a seperate listAdaptor from the one I already have to use with the onScroll listener? Thanks again for you help.

Comment: You need only one ListAdapter, created at very beggining. Each time new records are downloaded, you simply add them to this adapter. The onScroll method is part of OnScrollListener, which you set to your ListView like this: myListView.setOnScrollListener(newOnScrollListener() { @Override public void onScroll(...) { } });, which you can do in onCreate (or anywhere else).